# how to disable remember form data in nw.js

Tags: nw.js

i am new in nw.js and currently i am developing and sample app in nw.js. I downloaded nw.js 64bit and create an small login page and its working perfect. But when i login once it saves my login details and never removes even i restart my app many times but my details are still there.

can any one tell me how i can prevent nw.js chromium to save my login details.

[image]

MyCode:

```
<form method="POST" action="example.html" id="loginNow" autocomplete="nope">
<div class="login-card" style="margin-top: 10%;">
<h1>Log-in</h1><br>
<select name="usertype" style="width:100%; font-size: 13px; min-height: 30px; margin-bottom:3.5%;">
  <option>Select User Type</option>
  <option value="rps">RPS</option>
  <option value="gd">Godown</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" value="" autocomplete="nope">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" value="" autocomplete="nope">

<input type="submit" name="login" class="login login-submit" value="login" id="loginBut">

<div class="login-help">
 <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
 <a href="javascript:;" target="_blank" id="wind">Switch To Online</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think `autocomplete="nope"` should be changed to `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: yes, i was using `off` but not working

Comment: Which browser(s) are you testing with?

Comment: Your code should work. You are probably testing it locally but have previously saved your credentials while testing another project or so and that is why your browser populate credentials for you. Test it online - it will work well.. Or simple flush browser cache and test it over again ...

Comment: i think nw.js default using `chromium `

Comment: @salih0vocX: how online ?

Comment: i just placed my `index.html, package.json` in nw folder and simply running by click on `nw.exe`

Comment: In any case `"nope"` is not a valid value for the `autocomplete` attribute. Only `"on"` or `"off"` are valid. See this: [The Form Element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been driving me crazy.  Apparently Chromium ignores `autocomplete="off"` now.

The correct way to do this is to set `autocomplete="new-password"` on the `password` input, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30976223/2534036).

Answer (score 0):

Try this setting in your package.json:

> "chromium-args": "--disable-password-generation",

Comment: In that case a node.js function that clears all contents of C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Local\APP-NAME on program exit, should do the trick.

Comment: Wow...nice..i just change temp path by `--user-data-dir='temp/'` and clean it every time on app close..thanks..you can post this on answer...